# loop through a json within ranges with underscore

Tags: underscore.js

I'm looping through a json file as follows:

```
 <% _.each( looks, function( listItem, index ){ %>
                <li >
                    <a href="javascript:showDetailsView(<%= index %>)" class="look-btn" id="<%= listItem.id %>" data-look-id="<%= index %>">                        
                        <img src="<%= listItem.image %>" alt="<%= listItem.id %>"/>

                        <span class="seeLook"><localize id="13">See the Look</localize></span>
                    </a>
                </  li >
            <% }) %>
```

However I would only like to loop through say the first 5 items in the JSON file, or items 10 - 14, How could I do this?

The json file is as follows:

```
looks = [      
        {
        "id" : "look1",
        "image" : "/img/304x535/look1.jpg?$staticlink$",
        "imageLarge" : "/img/436x768/look1.jpg?$staticlink$",
        "products" : [
"hbeu50271612", "hbeu50274694", "hbeu50272802", "hbeu50276781", "hbeu50274296", "hbeu50272359"
]
        }
        ,
        {
        "id" : "look2",
        "image" : "/img/304x535/look2.jpg",
        "imageLarge" : "/img/436x768/look2.jpg",
        "products" : [
"hbeu50274106", "hbeu50273647", "hbeu50274754", "hbeu50274063", "hbeu50274911", "hbeu50274106", "hbeu50240022", "hbeu50271944"]
        },
......
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a solution for you, using underscore core and some javascript array function, hope this will work for you please do the edits according to your solution, I used less amount of elements in the demo , but this is a general solution to pick any range from a collection using underscore
Link : http://jsfiddle.net/ohx0chke/21/

```
   <h1>Result List</h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/template" id="look-template">
    <% _.each( looks, function( look){ 
        var listIndex = looks.indexOf(look)+1;
        if( listIndex >= start & listIndex <= end){
        %>
            <h1>pirnt ----<%- look.id %></h1>
    <% } }) %>
    </scirpt>

    var looks = [
           {
                'id' : 'look1',
                'uid' : '54915a9f4f26e',
                'unixtimestamp' : 1408210200
            },
           {
               'id' : 'look2',
               'uid' : '54915a9f519a2',
               'unixtimestamp' : 1408815000
            },
            {
               'id' : 'look3',
               'uid' : '54915a9f519a2',
               'unixtimestamp': 1408814467
            },
             {
               'id' : 'look4',
               'uid' : '54915a9f519a2',
               'unixtimestamp' : 1408815000
            },
            {
               'id' : 'look5',
               'uid' : '54915a9f519a2',
               'unixtimestamp': 1408814467
            }
            ,
            {
               'id' : 'look6',
               'uid' : '54915a9f519a2',
               'unixtimestamp': 1408814467
            }

    ];

    function print_list(start, end, datalist){           
        var compiled = _.template($('#look-template').html());    
        $('#result').html(compiled({looks: datalist, start: start, end: end}));
    } 

    print_list(2, 4, looks);
```